# Apache Jena: If I have the model and the data in a single file generated by Protegé: how do I use the ModelFactory.createInfModel method

Tags: owl, jena, protege

I just started using Apache Jena.
I am trying to use the Apache Jena reasoner on a .owl file generated by Protegé. I saved the file using the RDF / XML format. In that file is the schema and the individuals. I would like to make inferences. My problem is that I don't know how to create the inference model because in the examples I find, the schema is in a file and the data is in another file, that is, for example:

```
Model schema = RDFDataMgr.loadModel ("file: data / owlDemoSchema.owl");
Model data = RDFDataMgr.loadModel ("file: data / owlDemoData.rdf");
Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner ();
reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema (schema);
InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel (reasoner, data);
```

If I have the model and the data in a single file generated by Protegé: how do I use the ModelFactory.createInfModel method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can simply create an InfModel on the data containing both, the schema and the instance data. So just load your file into a model and use this model

Comment: @UninformedUser Good. Answer the question.